# JS needs to return all values ​when selecting the "все" option

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

the problem in the code is this: I can't think of how to return all elements when the "все" option is selected
I will be very grateful for any help

```
 <div class="filter-box">
                <div class="select-box">
                    <label class="filter-label">Категория</label>
                    <select id="cats" class="select-control">
                        <option value="0">Все</option>
                        <option value="1">Завтраки</option>
                        <option  value="2">Первые блюда</option>
                        <option  value="3">Гарниры</option>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- /.select-box -->
                <div class="price-select-box">
                    <label class="filter-label">Цена</label>
                    <select id="price" class="select-control">
                        <option value="0">Все</option>
                        <option value="30">До 30 грн</option>
                        <option value="50">До 50 грн</option>
                        <option value="100">До 100 грн</option>
                        <option value="150">До 150 грн</option>
                    </select>
                </div><!-- /.price-select-box -->
            </div>
<div id="products" class="products-box grid-box "> </div>

const products = document.getElementById("products");
const catsSel = document.getElementById("cats");
const priceSel = document.getElementById("price");
document.addEventListener('change', handleChange)
function handleChange(e) {
  const {target} = e;
  if(target.id !== "cats" && target.id !== "price") {
  return;
}
const selectedCat = parseInt(catsSel.value)
const selectedPrice = parseInt(priceSel.value)
const data = defaultData.products.filter((item) => {
  return (
    (selectedCat === -1 || item.cid === selectedCat) &&
    (selectedPrice === -1 || item.price <= selectedPrice) 
  )
})

render(data)

}


var defaultData = {
    cats: [
      { id: 1, title: "Все" },
      { id: 2, title: "Завтраки" },
      { id: 3, title: "Первые блюда" },
      { id: 4, title: "Гарниры" }
    ],
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        cid: 1,
        title: "Овсяная каша с фруктами",
        im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im1.jpg'>",
        price: 30
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        cid: 1,
        title: "Яичница глазунья с овощами на сковородке",
        im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im2.jpg'>",
        price: 25
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        cid: 1,
        title: "Сет азербайджанский завтрак",
        im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im3.jpg'>",
        price: 10
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        cid: 4,
        title: "Яичница с помидорами по-бакински",
        im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im4.jpg'>",
        price: 28
      },
      { id: 5, cid: 1, title: "Сырники со сметаной", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im5.jpg'>", price: 50},
      { id: 6, cid: 2, title: "Шпинатный крем-суп", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im6.jpg'>", price: 60},
      { id: 7, cid: 2, title: "Суп Пити", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im7.jpg'>", price: 118},
      { id: 8, cid: 2, title: "Борщ украинский", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im8.jpg'>", price: 68},
      { id: 9, cid: 2, title: "Суп Кюфта Бозбаш", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im9.jpg'>", price: 145},
      {
        id: 10,
        cid: 2,
        title: "Суп Соютма из ягненка",
        im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im10.jpg'>",
        price: 150
      },
      { id: 11, cid: 3, title: "Картофель фри", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im11.jpg'>", price: 35 },
      {
        id: 12,
        cid: 3,
        title: "Картофель по-домашнему",
        im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im12.jpg'>",
        price: 45
      }
    ],
  };
  
  var renderCats = defaultData.cats.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item.id] = item;
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

here is all the code https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-albattani-s0snm?file=/src/index.js

only there is an error, for some reason the variable is not visible from the data document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be 0 (value of “все” option)

```
    (selectedCat === 0
    (selectedPrice === 0
```

```js
const products = document.getElementById("products");
    const catsSel = document.getElementById("cats");
    const priceSel = document.getElementById("price");
    document.addEventListener('change', handleChange)
    function handleChange(e) {
      const {target} = e;
      if(target.id !== "cats" && target.id !== "price") {
      return;
    }
    const selectedCat = parseInt(catsSel.value)
    const selectedPrice = parseInt(priceSel.value)
    const data = defaultData.products.filter((item) => {
      return (
        (selectedCat === 0 || item.cid === selectedCat) &&
        (selectedPrice === 0 || item.price <= selectedPrice) 
      )
    })

    if (data.length !== 0) { render(data) }
    
    }

function render(data) {
  let output = '';
  for (const item of data) {
    output += item.im;
  }
  document.getElementById("render-box").innerHTML = output;
}

    var defaultData = {
        cats: [
          { id: 1, title: "Все" },
          { id: 2, title: "Завтраки" },
          { id: 3, title: "Первые блюда" },
          { id: 4, title: "Гарниры" }
        ],
        products: [
          {
            id: 1,
            cid: 1,
            title: "Овсяная каша с фруктами",
            im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im1.jpg'>",
            price: 30
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            cid: 1,
            title: "Яичница глазунья с овощами на сковородке",
            im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im2.jpg'>",
            price: 25
          },
          {
            id: 3,
            cid: 1,
            title: "Сет азербайджанский завтрак",
            im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im3.jpg'>",
            price: 10
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            cid: 4,
            title: "Яичница с помидорами по-бакински",
            im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im4.jpg'>",
            price: 28
          },
          { id: 5, cid: 1, title: "Сырники со сметаной", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im5.jpg'>", price: 50},
          { id: 6, cid: 2, title: "Шпинатный крем-суп", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im6.jpg'>", price: 60},
          { id: 7, cid: 2, title: "Суп Пити", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im7.jpg'>", price: 118},
          { id: 8, cid: 2, title: "Борщ украинский", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im8.jpg'>", price: 68},
          { id: 9, cid: 2, title: "Суп Кюфта Бозбаш", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im9.jpg'>", price: 145},
          {
            id: 10,
            cid: 2,
            title: "Суп Соютма из ягненка",
            im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im10.jpg'>",
            price: 150
          },
          { id: 11, cid: 3, title: "Картофель фри", im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im11.jpg'>", price: 35 },
          {
            id: 12,
            cid: 3,
            title: "Картофель по-домашнему",
            im: "<img class='img-fluid' src='i/im12.jpg'>",
            price: 45
          }
        ],
      };
      
      var renderCats = defaultData.cats.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc[item.id] = item;
        return acc;
      }, {});
```

```html
<div class="filter-box">
                    <div class="select-box">
                        <label class="filter-label">Категория</label>
                        <select id="cats" class="select-control">
                            <option value="0">Все</option>
                            <option value="1">Завтраки</option>
                            <option  value="2">Первые блюда</option>
                            <option  value="3">Гарниры</option>
                        </select>
                    </div><!-- /.select-box -->
                    <div class="price-select-box">
                        <label class="filter-label">Цена</label>
                        <select id="price" class="select-control">
                            <option value="0">Все</option>
                            <option value="30">До 30 грн</option>
                            <option value="50">До 50 грн</option>
                            <option value="100">До 100 грн</option>
                            <option value="150">До 150 грн</option>
                        </select>
                    </div><!-- /.price-select-box -->
                </div><!-- /filter-box-->
                <div id="render-box"></div>
```

Comment: does not work either in the sample code or in the editor

Comment: I added a screenshot. What is your problem?

Comment: the main issue with the "все" option has not been resolved, the program should return all 12 objects

Comment: Should the condition be either все or both все?

Comment: "Все" translate as all.T he first filter is the category of dishes, and the second filter is the price. if "все" is selected in the first input and in the second input, then all 12 ids should be returned.
 If only in the first "все" and in the second 100грн. then it should search among all dishes up to 100. And vice versa. if a dish is selected and in the second input "все" then all сid of these dishes should be returned.